# How to find the index for the second minimum number in a list?

Tags: python, list, loops, indexing

I have a list with 2 minimum numbers and I am trying to get the index of the minimum number 33 at index [5], but my loop stops at [0] once it's found the min. Unsure how to get the get last index value.

```
    rain_data =  [33, 57, 60, 55, 53, 33]
    min_value = rain_data[0]
    min_index = 0

    def minimum(rain_data)
    for val in range(len(rain_data)):
        if rain_data[val] < min_value:
            min_value = rain_data[val]
            min_index = val
    # display the min value and index
    print(min_value)
    print(min_index)
    results = (float(min_value) , min_index)
```

I have ran the loop and it stops at [0] and not the desired [5] index

Comment: I actually realize the question is ambiguous, you want the **second** item in the title, but you mention **last** in the question, which one it is?

Comment: I'm looking for the 33 in index [5]. The my list the are 2 numbers that are 33 (the minimum number). But my output is the first one in the [0]

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comment the question can be interpreted in different ways.

##### position of the LAST minimum

```
rain_data = [33, 57, 60, 55, 53, 33]

min_value = rain_data[0]
last_min_pos = 0
for i, x in enumerate(rain_data):
    if x <= min_value:
        min_value = x
        last_min_pos = i
```

Output: `5`

##### position of the NTH minimum (here second)

I would use a dictionary/list to keep track of the positions of each item and a loop to compute the min value.

This logic requires to read the list only once.

With a dictionary:

```
rain_data = [33, 57, 60, 55, 53, 33]

d = {}
min_val = rain_data[0]
for i, x in enumerate(rain_data):
    if x < min_val:
        min_val = x
    d.setdefault(x, []).append(i)

if len(d[min_val])>1:
    print(d[min_val][1])
```

Output: `5`

Same logic with a list:

```
l = []
min_val = rain_data[0]
for i, x in enumerate(rain_data):
    if x < min_val:
        min_val = x
        l = []
    if x == min_val:
        l.append(i)

if len(l)>1:
    print(l[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using <= min_value, then your answer will be 5.
Or make your min_index of type array, so you can store all the indexes in the array, so you will get a list of all the indexes where the minimum is found.

Comment: Hi Jonas, I don't think your array idea will work (in general) without tweaking the logic - if you just change `min_index = val` to `min_index.append(val)` this will pick out a descending subsequence rather than pointing out global minima. E.g. on [10,14,8,12,4,6,4] it gives me `min_index = [0,2,4,6]`. Only the last two elements refer to a minimum. I *think* you could get the minimum indices from this by starting at the end of min_index and extracting the longest constant subsequence you can, [4,6] in this example

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
rain_data = [33, 57, 60, 55, 53, 33]
minimum = min(rain_data)
out = [i for i,x in enumerate(rain_data) if x == minimum]
print(out[-1])
```

or

```
rain_data = [33, 57, 60, 55, 53, 33]
min_index = (len(rain_data) - 1) - rain_data[::-1].index(min(rain_data))
print(min_index)
```

```
5
```

Comment: Note that this requires to read the list twice